# Cargar listbox con criterio en VBA - Excel

Tags: excel, lista, vba, bucle-for, listbox

Estoy trabajando en un excel para trabajar con Alta/Baja/Modificacion de pedidos. En mi formulario de modificacion de pedidos tengo un listbox que muestra todos los pedidos en funcion al cliente seleccionado, actualmente funciona, pero me rellena el listbox ordenando todos los pedidos con ID creciente (foto 1)

[image: foto 1]

La BD que consulta es:

[image: foto 2]
El codigo que estoy utilizando para este fin es:

```
Private Sub cboCliente_Change()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = Worksheets("BD_PEDIDOS")
Me.ListBox1.Clear
Filas = WS.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To Filas
    If LCase(WS.Cells(i, 2).Value) Like "*" & LCase(Me.cboCliente.Value) & "*" Then 'filtra por empresa
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem WS.Cells(i, 1) 'pongo ID
        Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = WS.Cells(i, 4) 'pongo la fecha
        Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = WS.Cells(i, 3) 'pongo envio
        Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = WS.Cells(i, 6) 'pongo importe
    Else
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Lo que me gustaría que me ayuden es que los pedidos me aparezcan con la ID de mayor a menor (lo pedidos mas recientes primeros).

Pobre incorporando la funcion Step -1 pero no me funciona

```
For i = 2 To Filas Step -1
```

Espero sus respuestas! Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si ya tienes tu código la cantidad de celdas, lo unico que tienes que hacer es recorrer el For con el Step-1 como en tu prueba, pero en lugar de iniciar en 2 tienes que iniciar en tu variable final.

```
For i = Filas To 2 Step -1
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ya funcionó... la verdad que no me di cuenta ERROR MUY DE ROOKIE jajajaa. Saludos eduardo!